# Вывести из базы mysql в виде json массива.

Tags: json, php, javascript, mysql

Здравствуйте!
Нужно с помощью php реализовать вывод json массива, визуальный его вид такой:

```
{"akk":[["1","Dmitry","Novickov"],["2","Evgenuy","Novickov"]]}
```

Нужно выводить именно таким JSON массивом..
Пожалуйста помогите это реализовать.

Comment: вам следовало не менять формулировку вопроса, а новый создать. Этот вопрос почти ничего общего не имеет с тем, который был изначально.

Comment: А вообще вам нужно просто разобраться с тем, как php-функция json_encode преобразует массивы в json. Чтобы получился js-массив, исходный массив должен быть индексированным, если исходный был ассоциативным, получится js-объект.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Для начала вам следовало показать и как вы из базы выбираете, а то сейчас остаётся только догадываться.

На самом деле всё относительно просто.

```
$data = array(); // в этот массив запишем то, что выберем из базы

$ta = mysql_query("select * from table"); // сделаем запрос в БД
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ta)){ // оформим каждую строку результата
                                      // как ассоциативный массив
    $data[] = $row; // допишем строку из выборки как новый элемент результирующего массива
}
echo json_encode($data); // и отдаём как json
```

Answer (score 2):

В визуальном редакторе `mysql`, есть функция `Export` с выбором формата. Можно экспортировать как всю базу, так и отдельную таблицу.

Выводит в формате:

```
[{"USER":"634155305","ID_GREP":"109927", ... },{..}]
```

Достаточно будет заменить регулярные скобки в любом текстовом редакторе или `preg_replace` вам в руки.